# How to hide view when animation ends?

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-animation, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using the curlup and curldown animation that works great. My problem is my view is still present for a second before it pushes the viewcontroller. How do I hide current view when animation ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the view's alpha to to 0 once animation is complete like:

```
[customView setAlpha:0];
```

Comment: Works great when I flip forward, but when I try to go back it gives me a blank view. I'm using a popviewcontroller to flip back... [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Comment: you have to handle it again in viewWillAppear by setting it's alpha to 1

Comment: Works! I'm getting last view for a few seconds when I flip back to original view.

Comment: I have [self.view alpha:1]; in viewWillAppear... that's it. Is it something with my views?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this code will help to u....

once check it..... .

when your animation completed at that time "customView" frame sizes are set (x,y,0,0).... like below

```
-(void)close_but{   
CGRect viewTopFrame = CGRectMake(150,240,0,0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
            delay:0
            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
             animations:^{
                 "customView".frame = viewTopFrame;

                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];
customView.frame=viewTopFrame;
```